# In Python, how do I make a Priority Queue pop off multiple values of an object?

Tags: python, class, compare

I have a priority queue of class objects. In my class definition I have:

```
def __lt__(self, other):
    return self.fn < other.fn
```

In the event where there are multiple objects that have the same `fn` value, how do I incorporate a 'tie breaker'? In other words, something like this:

```
def __lt__(self, other):
    return self.fn < other.fn and self.gn < other.gn
```

Comment: I think the title and body ask two different questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an explicit check for equality between the two `fn` fields, only checking `gn` if they're equal:

```py
def __lt__(self, other):
    if self.fn != other.fn:
        return self.fn < other.fn
    return self.gn < other.gn
```